# I'm trying to run Efficientdet on NVIDIA GPU, but not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run efficientdet(https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet) with custom data on GPU. But the GPUs look to seem not working when training.

My environment:

- O/S: Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5120 CPU @2.20GHz
- GPU: Tesla V100 * 2 (The machine has 2 GPUs)
- CUDA ver: 10.1 Tensorflow ver: 2.1.0 Tensorflow-gpu ver: 2.1.0

(Comment me if any further info abut the device is needed)

The running code I have tried:

```
python main.py
    --mode=train_and_eval
    --training_file_pattern=custom_data/fruit-tfrecord/train*.tfrecord
    --validation_file_pattern=custom_data/fruit-tfrecord/val*.tfrecord
    --model_name=efficientdet-d0
    --model_dir=efficientdet-d0-fruit
    --ckpt=efficientdet-d0
    --train_batch_size=64 --eval_batch_size=32
    --eval_samples=128 --num_examples_per_epoch=12 --num_epochs=5
    --hparams=custom_data/fruit-custom_config.yaml
    --strategy=gpus
```

The GPU status is as following while training the efficientdet:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   35C    P0    37W / 250W |    318MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:06.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   35C    P0    36W / 250W |    318MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

The memory allocation is fine, but I think other status like power usage, temp imply that the GPUs not working when training. I don't see why the GPU is not working.

The part of output message after running the training command that I'm guessing it is suspicious is as following(if you want to see the whole output, it is the bottom of this post):

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
I1216 10:12:53.499559 140591316670208 mirrored_strategy.py:435] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
I1216 10:12:53.500708 140591316670208 run_config.py:566] Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
I1216 10:12:53.500859 140591316670208 estimator_training.py:167] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
```

The line 'Not using Distrubute Coordinator' is the part that I guess it might be the problem.
Please let me know if anyone has any helpful thoughts. Thank you!

P.S.
Oh, I almost forgot to mention this output:

```
2020-12-16 10:31:50.718589: W tensorflow/core/grappler/utils/graph_view.cc:832] No registered 'MultiDeviceIteratorFromStringHandle' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node {{node MultiDeviceIteratorFromStringHandle}}
    .  Registered:  device='CPU'
```

the whole command output:

```
2020-12-16 10:12:51.711513: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib::/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow
2020-12-16 10:12:51.711636: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib::/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow
2020-12-16 10:12:51.711648: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
I1216 10:12:53.200553 140591316670208 main.py:228] {'name': 'efficientdet-d0', 'act_type': 'swish', 'image_size': (512, 512), 'target_size': None, 'input_rand_hflip': True, 'jitter_min': 0.1, 'jitter_max': 2.0, 'autoaugment_policy': None, 'grid_mask': False, 'sample_image': None, 'map_freq': 5, 'num_classes': 8, 'seg_num_classes': 3, 'heads': ['object_detection'], 'skip_crowd_during_training': True, 'label_map': {0: 'background', 1: 'apple', 2: 'banana', 3: 'grape', 4: 'kiwi', 5: 'pear', 6: 'persimmon', 7: 'tomato'}, 'max_instances_per_image': 100, 'regenerate_source_id': False, 'min_level': 3, 'max_level': 7, 'num_scales': 3, 'aspect_ratios': [1.0, 2.0, 0.5], 'anchor_scale': 4.0, 'is_training_bn': True, 'momentum': 0.9, 'optimizer': 'sgd', 'learning_rate': 0.08, 'lr_warmup_init': 0.008, 'lr_warmup_epoch': 1.0, 'first_lr_drop_epoch': 200.0, 'second_lr_drop_epoch': 250.0, 'poly_lr_power': 0.9, 'clip_gradients_norm': 10.0, 'num_epochs': 5, 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'label_smoothing': 0.0, 'alpha': 0.25, 'gamma': 1.5, 'delta': 0.1, 'box_loss_weight': 50.0, 'iou_loss_type': None, 'iou_loss_weight': 1.0, 'weight_decay': 4e-05, 'strategy': 'gpus', 'mixed_precision': False, 'loss_scale': None, 'model_optimizations': {}, 'box_class_repeats': 3, 'fpn_cell_repeats': 3, 'fpn_num_filters': 64, 'separable_conv': True, 'apply_bn_for_resampling': True, 'conv_after_downsample': False, 'conv_bn_act_pattern': False, 'drop_remainder': True, 'nms_configs': {'method': 'gaussian', 'iou_thresh': None, 'score_thresh': 0.0, 'sigma': None, 'pyfunc': False, 'max_nms_inputs': 0, 'max_output_size': 100}, 'fpn_name': None, 'fpn_weight_method': None, 'fpn_config': None, 'survival_prob': None, 'img_summary_steps': None, 'lr_decay_method': 'cosine', 'moving_average_decay': 0.9998, 'ckpt_var_scope': None, 'skip_mismatch': True, 'backbone_name': 'efficientnet-b0', 'backbone_config': None, 'var_freeze_expr': '(efficientnet|fpn_cells|resample_p6)', 'use_keras_model': True, 'dataset_type': None, 'positives_momentum': None, 'grad_checkpoint': False, 'model_name': 'efficientdet-d0', 'iterations_per_loop': 100, 'model_dir': 'efficientdet-d0-fruit', 'num_shards': 8, 'num_examples_per_epoch': 12, 'backbone_ckpt': '', 'ckpt': 'efficientdet-d0', 'val_json_file': None, 'testdev_dir': None, 'profile': False, 'mode': 'train_and_eval'}
2020-12-16 10:12:53.202116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.209516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.210739: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:05.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-12-16 10:12:53.210812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.212006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:06.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-12-16 10:12:53.212209: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.214371: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.216370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.216677: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.218827: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.220044: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.224927: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-16 10:12:53.225053: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.226304: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.227528: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.228714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.229867: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.230203: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-12-16 10:12:53.239567: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2200010000 Hz
2020-12-16 10:12:53.240516: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x559801065720 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-16 10:12:53.240540: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-12-16 10:12:53.466568: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.477795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.479306: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5598010cb6f0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-16 10:12:53.479349: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2020-12-16 10:12:53.479357: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (1): Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2020-12-16 10:12:53.479808: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.481001: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:05.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-12-16 10:12:53.481088: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482246: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:06.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482346: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482361: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482376: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482391: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-12-16 10:12:53.482457: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.483651: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.484812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.485969: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.487129: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.487228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-12-16 10:12:53.490398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-12-16 10:12:53.490416: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 1 
2020-12-16 10:12:53.490424: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N N 
2020-12-16 10:12:53.490429: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 1:   N N 
2020-12-16 10:12:53.490591: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.491810: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.492997: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.494174: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30263 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:05.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2020-12-16 10:12:53.494703: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-16 10:12:53.495907: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 30263 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:06.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
I1216 10:12:53.499559 140591316670208 mirrored_strategy.py:435] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
I1216 10:12:53.500708 140591316670208 run_config.py:566] Initializing RunConfig with distribution strategies.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
I1216 10:12:53.500859 140591316670208 estimator_training.py:167] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'efficientdet-d0-fruit', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategyV1 object at 0x7fdd501a14e0>, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_distribute_coordinator_mode': None}
I1216 10:12:53.501142 140591316670208 estimator.py:216] Using config: {'_model_dir': 'efficientdet-d0-fruit', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategyV1 object at 0x7fdd501a14e0>, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_distribute_coordinator_mode': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'efficientdet-d0-fruit', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategyV1 object at 0x7fdd501a14e0>, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_distribute_coordinator_mode': None}
I1216 10:12:53.502187 140591316670208 estimator.py:216] Using config: {'_model_dir': 'efficientdet-d0-fruit', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategyV1 object at 0x7fdd501a14e0>, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_distribute_coordinator_mode': None}
I1216 10:12:53.504521 140591316670208 main.py:334] found ckpt at step 46 (epoch 245)
```

Comment: try on a single GPU first using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python main.py ...`

Comment: This message looks like warning but not an error. You can also find similar warning messages in Tensorflow site https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_estimator#train_and_evaluate_the_model. Thanks!

Comment: @y.selivonchyk Thank you. I tried to run on a single GPU, and also only a CPU.
But the training ended with error too.